Auto scheduling in MS project
I have these tasks as an example with the dates shown. I have around 200 cells. Is there any way I can automatically input the dates depending on the duration each task takes?
Thank you!
here is the link for the photo:
https://imgur.com/a/OakaX2g

To answer your question, yes. It appears you have set up your plan using manual schedule mode (as evidenced by your text entry in the Duration field). I see you have also set up your plan's logical sequence of tasks based on entries in the Predecessor field. Great. Now add the Task Mode field as a column in the view and set the first task to Auto Scheduled. Then do a fill down to the rest of your plan. All duration values are by default in working time, not calendar time, and working time is defined by your Project calendar. If you have not created a custom calendar, by default it will be the Standard calendar of 8-5 with tasks starting at 8:00 AM.
Now you should go to, File > Options > Schedule group and set "New tasks created" to Auto Scheduled.
If you need to modify the Project calendar to say, start at 7:00 AM or reflect a 6 day workweek, go to, Project > Properties group > Change Working Time. Do NOT directly edit the Standard calendar, rather, hit the "Create new calendar" button, give your custom calendar a name, and edit work hours and days as needed. Once your new calendar is created, go to, Project > Properties group > Project Information and select you new custom calendar as the Project Calendar.

I agree with the answer provided by @john-project. Here is just an image of the task mode column in the Gantt Chart view:

you want everything task to have this icon:

